# How can one optimize black-box functions given context?

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, bayesian-optimization, contextual-bandit

Libraries like *hyperopt* or *scikit-optimize* allow one to optimize a black-box function. However, they *do not* allow specifying contextual information *outside of* the parameters to be chosen by the acquisition function. **Is there a similar (to skopt) library or methodology that essentially performs the same thing as hyperparameter optimization (global noisy function optimization) where known, fixed state or context is allowed to be specified**?

Hypothetical problem for motivation:

> Suppose I own an umbrella shop, in which I am able to control
>   *price*, *ad spend*, etc. But I also want to specify an important boolean, *rain_forecasted* as context to be provided to my optimization objective, even though I have no
>   control over it. Thus, I will need to find the optimal function parameters, given one parameter that is outside of my control.  I am concerned with cumulative regret; not just
>   finding the best-possible choice as in hyperparameter optimization.
>   E.g. I want to maximize sales over all time. The maximum target
>   response is bounded, but is also noisy.

Maybe I should be implementing something custom with `GaussianProcessRegressor`?

Comment: have you had a look at https://esa.github.io/pygmo/. you can specify your loss function on many optimisation algorithms